# How to distribute NIntegrate of four different integrals into four different cores

Tags: numerical-integration, parallelization

I'm not familiar at using parallel computing in Mathematica. I have a combination of an NIntegrate and Sum to evaluate a function which takes about 1 hour to run.

Is there any way that I can break it down using parallel computing in Mathematica such that each part will run in a different processor to make it faster?

Or, is there a way I can run 4 different Mathematica files that will run simultaneously on 4 different cores and then compile the results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen `ParallelSum`?

Comment: yes I've tried it and it made my code run twice as fast :D however, is there a way that i can run 4 different mathematica files that will run simultaneously on 4 different cores and then compile the results?

Comment: Depends on what _Mathematica_ licence you have. Different licences allow different number of concurrent processes.

Comment: ok. so assuming I have that licence, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the simplest way to evaluate multiple expressions in parallel is [`Parallelize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html).

Example:

```
Parallelize[{$KernelID, $KernelID}]
(* {4, 3} *)
```

However, I would be cautious with `NIntegrate` because it is already parallelized internally.  Test this by watching your CPU usage while it is running.  Parallelizing manually is likely to reduce performance in this case, not increase it.  The one exception is when parallelizing across several computers (not several CPUs).

Comment: thanks! my code runs almost three times faster now :D